# Using dot-notation on a JSON column in a view in Oracle

Tags: json, oracle

I am trying to figure out how to pull a JSON column from a table into a view and still be able to use dot-notation in the `WHERE` clause.

I currently have the column defined correctly and I can use dot-notation in the `WHERE` clause in a query that hits the table directly. The problem I am having is that this table is currently used in a view that I need to use to return all pertinent data.

If I simply include the column in the view definition, I lose the ability to search values in the string using dot-notation.

If I join the view back to this table in the query where I retrieve data from the view, I am able to use dot-notation in the `WHERE` clause, but, I take a huge performance hit (4-5 times slower).

Here is a sample of the JSON that would be stored in each row.

```
{"fields": 
  {
    "field1":{ "name": "field1","label": "My Field 1","value": "ABCD"},
    "field2":{ "name": "field2","label": "My Field 2","value": ""},
    "field3":{ "name": "field3","label": "My Field 3","value": "XYZ"},
    "field4":{ "name": "field4","label": "My Field 4","value": ""},
    "field5":{ "name": "field5","label": "My Field 5","value": ""},
    "field6":{ "name": "field6","label": "My Field 6","value": "Y"},
    "field7":{ "name": "field7","label": "My Field 7","value": ""}
  }
}
```

What I would like to be able to do in the view is `WHERE json_col_name.fields.field1.value = 'ABCD'`

Please keep in mind that the object keys, such as `field1`, `field2`, etc will be arbitrary values, not always following that naming convention nor will there always be 7 fields.

I am not married to this schema and would gladly change it to get it to work.

Here is the SQL to reproduce the table/view and data.

```
create table MAIN_TABLE
(
    ID NUMBER(10) not null
        constraint MY_PK
            primary key,

    JSON_DATA CLOB
        constraint JSON_DATA_CONST
            check (JSON_DATA IS JSON)
)

INSERT INTO MAIN_TABLE (ID, JSON_DATA) VALUES (1, '{"fields": {"field1":{ "name": "field1","label": "My Field 1","value": "ABCD"},"field2":{ "name": "field2","label": "My Field 2","value": "XYZ"},"field3":{ "name": "field3","label": "My Field 3","value": "Y"},"field4":{ "name": "field4","label": "My Field 4","value": ""},"field5":{ "name": "field5","label": "My Field 5","value": ""},"field6":{ "name": "field6","label": "My Field 6","value": ""},"field7":{ "name": "field7","label": "My Field 7","value": ""},}}');

INSERT INTO MAIN_TABLE (ID, JSON_DATA) VALUES (2, '{"fields": {"field1":{ "name": "field1","label": "My Field 1","value": ""},"field2":{ "name": "field2","label": "My Field 2","value": "XYZ"},"field3":{ "name": "field3","label": "My Field 3","value": "Y"},"field4":{ "name": "field4","label": "My Field 4","value": "QWERTY"},"field5":{ "name": "field5","label": "My Field 5","value": ""},"field6":{ "name": "field6","label": "My Field 6","value": ""},"field7":{ "name": "field7","label": "My Field 7","value": ""},}}');

create or replace view JSON_TEST_VIEW as
select id, JSON_DATA
from MAIN_TABLE
union all
select id, JSON_DATA from MAIN_TABLE;
```

This query, that hits the table, works as expected.

```
select * from MAIN_TABLE m where m.json_data.fields.field1.value='ABCD'
```

This query, that hits the view, throws an `invalid identifier` error.

```
select * from JSON_TEST_VIEW jtv where jtv.JSON_DATA.fields.field1.value='ABCD'
```

I am fairly certain that the issue stems from the `UNION` as I was not initially seeing the issue in my repro case without adding it (The original view has a `UNION`)

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of the problem.

Comment: Can you give an example of the query you are using, both against the table and against the view, along with the definitions of the table and the view?

Comment: I am working on simplifying the table and view definitions.

Comment: @pmdba I have updated the question with the necessary SQL to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dot notation is only valid for JSON that has tagged with the "IS JSON" check constraint.

On your table, we *know* that the data is JSON, but once you put it into a view, then we no longer have that confidence. After all you could have done.

```
create view V as
select [some json]
union all
select [some junk]
```

So in this case, you'll need to let us know that the JSON can indeed be treated as such.

```
SQL> create or replace view JSON_TEST_VIEW as
  2  select m.id,  treat(m.json_data as json) JSON_DATA
  3  from
  4  (
  5    select id, JSON_DATA
  6    from MAIN_TABLE
  7    union all
  8    select id, JSON_DATA from MAIN_TABLE
  9  ) m;

View created.

SQL>
SQL> select * from JSON_TEST_VIEW jtv where jtv.JSON_DATA.fields.field1.value='ABCD';

        ID JSON_DATA
---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 {"fields": {"field1":{ "name": "field1","label": "My Field 1","value": "ABCD"},"
           field2":{ "name": "field2","label": "My Field 2","value": "XYZ"},"field3":{ "nam
           e": "field3","label": "My Field 3","value": "Y"},"field4":{ "name": "field4","la
           bel": "My Field 4","value": ""},"field5":{ "name": "field5","label": "My Field 5
           ","value": ""},"field6":{ "name": "field6","label": "My Field 6","value": ""},"f
           ield7":{ "name": "field7","label": "My Field 7","value": ""},}}

         1 {"fields": {"field1":{ "name": "field1","label": "My Field 1","value": "ABCD"},"
           field2":{ "name": "field2","label": "My Field 2","value": "XYZ"},"field3":{ "nam
           e": "field3","label": "My Field 3","value": "Y"},"field4":{ "name": "field4","la
           bel": "My Field 4","value": ""},"field5":{ "name": "field5","label": "My Field 5
           ","value": ""},"field6":{ "name": "field6","label": "My Field 6","value": ""},"f
           ield7":{ "name": "field7","label": "My Field 7","value": ""},}}
```